# Добавление команд "опробуйте мои команды"

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Как реализовать в отображении информации о пользователе следующую информацию

- Играет в /help
- Опробуйте мои команды (список команд, нажав на которую, она подставляется шаблоном в чат)(пример: MEE6)
  Язык python, используемая библиотека - disnake

[image: пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73462296/discord-js-how-do-i-add-the-try-my-commands-feature-to-my-bot вот примерное решение, но там не написано "опробуйте мои команды"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Теперь суть ясна. Бот должен пройти верификацию, тогда добавятся 5 команд(по какому признаку, не понял). Иначе уготован "костыльный" вариант. В целом, это и есть решение. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот как реализовать "стримит /help"

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user.name}')
  await bot.change_presence(status=disnake.Status.idle,
                            activity=disnake.Activity(
                                type=disnake.ActivityType.streaming,
                                name='/help',
                                url="https://www.twitch.tv/AncharNils"))
```

https://www.twitch.tv/AncharNils Ник можно заменить на любой всё ровно будет работать
а как реализовать "опробуйте мои команды" я сам ищу

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Пните, когда появится ответ на "пробные команды"